# invalid parameter number exception using named parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting "invalid parameter number:parameter undefined" exception when attempting an insert query to mysql database.

I am returning the result to my Android app as json.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) 
{

$query = "INSERT INTO attendance (tdate,slot_from,slot_to,coursecode,stud_id,remark) VALUES (:dat,:fromm,:too,:ccode,:stud,:rmk ) ";


$query_params = array(
    ':dat' => $_POST['datee'],
    ':from'=>$_POST['fromm'],
    ':to'=>$_POST['too'],
    ':ccode'=>$_POST['course'],
    ':stud'=>$_POST['sname'],
    ':rmk'=>$_POST['remark'],
    );

try 
{
     $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
     $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    }
catch (PDOException $ex) 
{

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = $ex->getMessage();
    $response["date"] = $_POST['datee'];
    $response["from"] = $_POST['fromm'];
    $response["to"] = $_POST['too'];
    $response["ccode"] = $_POST['course'];
    $response["stud"] = $_POST['sname'];
    $response["remark"] = $_POST['remark'];
            die(json_encode($response));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you lack a `m` in

```
':from'=>$_POST['fromm'],
```

should be

```
':fromm'=>$_POST['fromm'],
```

you must be careful when using named parameter, I myself am very prone to making such errors

that's why I more easily use the `?` placeholder, this way in your exemple:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO attendance (tdate,slot_from,slot_to,coursecode,stud_id,remark) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

$query_params = array(
    $_POST['datee'],
    $_POST['fromm'],
    $_POST['too'],
    $_POST['course'],
    $_POST['sname'],
    $_POST['remark'],
    );
```

then:

```
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
```

you must be sure that the params are in good order (same as in query)

Comment: @felix gagon thanks a lot. i miss spelled 'o' in 'too' too.. too careless

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you're misspelling `from`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO attendance (tdate,slot_from,slot_to,coursecode,stud_id,remark) VALUES (:dat,:fromm,:too,:ccode,:stud,:rmk ) ";
```

Replace it with:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO attendance (tdate,slot_from,slot_to,coursecode,stud_id,remark) VALUES (:dat,:from,:too,:ccode,:stud,:rmk ) ";
```